# jQuery Text Manipulation Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i'm trying to do is this

```
<span>0%</span>
```

I want jQuery to start counting from 0% to a given value .
I have 3 spans each are at 0% but when I click, let say a button, they go from 0%, 1%, 2%, 3%  automatic at a certain speed until it reaches it's given value eg... 99%. Is this possible? thanks.!

I'm not using images as numbers, only text.

Comment: Pls make your question clear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: OK, a single button click should kick off automatic updates of three spans each going to a different total:

```
<span id="percentSpan1">0%</span>
<span id="percentSpan2">0%</span>
<span id="percentSpan3">0%</span>
<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start">

<script>
$("#startButton").click(function() {
   var spans = {"percentSpan1" : 99,
                "percentSpan2" : 40,
                "percentSpan3" : 20},
       speed = 3000; // ms

   for (var k in spans) {
      (function(spanId) {
         var currentPercent = 0,
             intervalID = setInterval(function() {
                 $("#" + spanId).text(++currentPercent + "%");
                 if (currentPercent === spans[spanId])
                     clearInterval(intervalID);
             }, Math.floor(speed / spans[spanId]));
      })(k);
   }
});

</script>
```

<s>You don't make it clear if the three spans you talk about are supposed to be linked to a single button, or if they're supposed to go to the same maximum percentage value, so I'll leave that part to you.</s>

Comment: no ummm each span needs to go to a different value on one click lets say one goes to 99% another to 40 and another to 20%

Comment: also the speed is no fast enough

Comment: You could've made that a lot clearer initially. Anyway, I've updated my answer. Regarding the speed: what do _you_ think you need to do to fix that?

Comment: Thankyou so much nnnnnn for your time this is exactly was i was looking for... :)

Comment: yeah sorry for not beign  clear enough, and on the speed i manage to fix it thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines (test here: http://jsfiddle.net/KP2BL/):

```
<span id="span1">0%</span>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click Me"></input>

<script>
    jQuery("#btn").click(function() 
    {
        var value = parseInt(jQuery("#span1").text())
        jQuery("#span1").text(value + 1 + "%")
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Andrey is it possible for it to be just one click lets say one click it starts counting from 0%, 1%, 2%  at a certain speed until it reaches 99% then it stops.?